# Do TV channels take context into account when deciding to censor certain words?

Tags: censorship

I'm recently watching "How I Met Your Mother" again, and I'm noticing some weirdness. In early seasons, the word "bitch" was used a couple of times, i.e. Season 2 Episode 4 *Ted Mosby: Architect* Robin says "I love being the person you bitch to". Yet in another episode much later, they censor it, i.e. Season 2 Episode 11 *How Lily Stole Christmas* Ted tells Lily "You were kind of a grinch", but the narration hints that he meant 'bitch'. Was it censored due to the context?

Comment: It would be interesting to know *how* it was censored. Do you mean it's actually bleeped away or do the characters paraphrase it or replace it with a different word? I'm asking because HIMYM is famous for doing meta-humour like that, since it is still Ted who tells the story to his kids (e.g. like they tend to replace joints with sandwiches). Thus, it would be good to know what specific episodes you're talking about, or at least *what kind* of "censoring".

Comment: The FCC doesn't censor anything. They set out a set Standard & Practices that the program makers try to adhere to. Any *censoring* would have been done by the network....if any.

Comment: https://www.fcc.gov/consumers/guides/obscene-indecent-and-profane-broadcasts

Comment: Interesting note:  the pop culture news show TMZ will allow people to say the word "bitch" (as a noun) but when they show text of what a person says, they replace the word with asterisks *****. It's weird when they're showing their own subtitles while a person is being interviewed, and the person says "bitch" while the subtitles show *****.

Comment: +1 Napoleon.  It's hard to answer authoritatively without knowing the exact context where the word was censored, but from what I recall of watching the show myself, the only time bad words were "bleeped out" it was intended as a joke (ie: Ted is censoring the dialogue as he re-tells the story to his kids, so we the audience hear bleeps.)

Comment: @NapoleonWilson I added some clarification.

Comment: If it's a Christmas episode, saying "Grinch" makes sense, though.

Comment: Censoring by replacing with a similar word is called ***bowlderizing***. Fuck to frak, hell to heck, etc.

Comment: To pick a different example to answer the question in the title, there was a Tosh.0 episode where Daniel read a list of words and phrases that were bleeped in previous episodes. Without their original context, they were unbleeped.

Comment: @MyCodeSucks Um, yeah, in that case, total HIMYM joke, nothing else. Which causes a bit of conflict, since it could get an interesting HIMYM-specific answer elaborating on that kind of humour, but that wouldn't answer your general question that much.

Comment: Maybe it's automatic. I remember watching an American show on an African (and very religious) network that censored the word 'Lord', even when when it was mentioned in the word 'landlord' and the phrase 'I don't want to lord it over you'.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is a little problematic (in a good way, though), because it's actually based on a false premise/example and makes much more sense as a *How I Met Your Mother* question than as a general TV question.

I can't really say much about the general question if TV channels censor content based on dialogue context, however, I'd doubt that, since that would involve far too much work. While TV channels are known to sometimes even redub scenes of movies with a higher rating with different words for making them "appropriate" (e.g. Sam Jackson's famous line from *Snakes on a Plane* about "monkey-fightin'" snakes on a "monday-to-friday" plane), they would rather have a blacklist of "bad" words you can say than assess each and every scene on its own, let alone take care of fitting any possible replacement words to an overall christmas theme. But so much to my general and rather unbacked statements.

But the much more interesting question here is specifically about *How I Met You Mother* and its ways of storytelling, since you actually picked a very interesting example. In this specific episode **this is all entirely the show doing the "censorship" and that on purpose**. You have to keep in mind that this is all still Ted Mosby telling a story to his kids and **the show is famous for occasionally playing with this concept of an unreliable narrator**. Other examples for this would be:

- Ted revealing at some point that in all the previous episodes all the characters were actually heavy smokers and smoked all the time.
- The whole physical and narrative replacement of joints with sandwiches.

Of course it's not always entirely consistent, as you pointed out yourself. Sometimes he censors stuff as innocuous as "shit" and other times he freely talks about Barney's kinky adventures with his "dates". But they don't use it for censorship at all, since those are all concepts you could talk about freely in a TV-show. They use it entirely as a **story-telling technique for humourous effect, illustrating the actual frame-narrative structure** of the show.

So Ted calling Lily a grinch instead of a bitch in this episode does not only cater into this common motif but also adds to the christmas theme of the episode. So yes, it ***was* censored due to the context, but *no* it wasn't done by the TV channel nor for the sole purpose of censorship**.